# How to transfer loop values to another table PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to transfer my loop values in another table after submit button

Here's my code

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('Select * from productbottomtopstiches WHERE
productsrfinformationID = :prodID');

$stmt->bindParam(':prodID', $srfid, PDO::PARAM_INT);

$stmt->execute();
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $topstichescode= $row['topstichescode'];
    $color = $row['color'];
    $topstichestkt = $row['topstichestkt'];

    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO productpifbottomtopstiches(
        productpifinformationID,
        topstichescode,
        color,
        topstichestkt
        )
        VALUES(
        :pid,
        :code,
        :color,
        :tkt
        )");

    $stmt->execute(array(
       ':pid' => $srfid,
       ':code' => $topstichescode,
       ':color' => $color,
       ':tkt' => $topstichestkt ));
 }
```

The values from productbottomtopstiches are 3

It displays 3 values different ID, Code, Color and TKT but when i added the insert code it only save the first value in the loop the 2nd and 3rd value is missing..

can someone help me to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to prepare the query inside the loop. Prepare it once before the loop, and execute it each time through the loop with different values.

Comment: as an alternative, you can just use one query, bind your "prodID" with a insert select query

Comment: How can there be different ID? ID is just `$srfid`, which doesn't change. Is that a unique column in the table?

Comment: @Ghost I suggest you show how to do this in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative, you can just join the queries altogether into one. This also takes out the need of fetching, then looping the first select query and executing multiple statements. But the binding of that ID will still be there:

Example:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('
    INSERT INTO productpifbottomtopstiches(
        productpifinformationID,
        topstichescode,
        color,
        topstichestkt
    )
    SELECT productsrfinformationID, topstichescode, color, topstichestkt FROM 
    productbottomtopstiches WHERE productsrfinformationID = :prodID
');

$stmt->bindParam(':prodID', $srfid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

But for whatever reason, you still want to continue this route, move the second prepare outside and into another container:

```
// first statement
$stmt = $db->prepare('Select * from productbottomtopstiches WHERE
productsrfinformationID = :prodID');

$stmt->bindParam(':prodID', $srfid, PDO::PARAM_INT);

$stmt->execute();

// second statement
$stmt2 = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO productpifbottomtopstiches(
        productpifinformationID,
        topstichescode,
        color,
        topstichestkt
    )
    VALUES(
        :pid,
        :code,
        :color,
        :tkt
)");

while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $topstichescode = $row['topstichescode'];
    $color = $row['color'];
    $topstichestkt = $row['topstichestkt'];

    // execute second statement
    $stmt2->execute(array(
        ':pid' => $srfid,
        ':code' => $topstichescode,
        ':color' => $color,
        ':tkt' => $topstichestkt
    ));
}
```

And in case you're wondering the reason why is it just inserting once is because, you used the same `$stmt` variable into preparing into the second inside the loop, overwriting the first prepared statement that you wished to be looped. That's why it stopped after the first insertion.

Comment: Wow! Your the best! Thank you for helping your the best ghost ever! Do you have a school i want to enroll hehe. I'm new in php. Thanks again.

Comment: @user5598179 no, don't have one, and not planning to have one too haha :D glad this helped

Comment: Please have one! haha.